# add 1 class to another class array

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have 2 classes:

1 which contains the data and another that contain an array

how can I create a function that add that class (like a list)

```
class Event(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.msg_idx=0 ## the message from the panel
        self.evt_id=0 ## the event id given by the server
        self.Panel_Number=0 ## the panel number
        self.line=""

    def updateData(self,msg,event,panel,line):
        self.msg_idx =msg
        self.evt_id = event
        self.Panel_Number = panel
        self.line =line


class Events(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.event =[]

    def addEvent(self, Server_Event):
         ????????
```

Comment: Have you tried `append` yet?

Comment: `self.event.append(Server_Event)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Literally just append:

```
class Event(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.msg_idx=0 ## the message from the panel
        self.evt_id=0 ## the event id given by the server
        self.Panel_Number=0 ## the panel number
        self.line=""

    def updateData(self,msg,event,panel,line):
        self.msg_idx =msg
        self.evt_id = event
        self.Panel_Number = panel
        self.line =line


class Events(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.event =[]

    def addEvent(self, Server_Event):
         self.event.append(Server_Event)

something = Event()
somethings = Events()
somethings.addEvent(something)
```

I would question why you need such a class right now, when you could just use a list called events. But I have done something similar before and I know it makes it easier to add metadata on top.

However if you're just using it for the above without any extra analysis, it would be more efficient to just use a list.